# como definir o array de entrada para o treinamento da RNA no pacote rnn?

Tags: array, r, redes-neurais

No pacote `rnn` há um exemplo de como proceder para realizar o treinamento da rede, o qual está descrito neste [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/vignettes/rnn.html) (exemplo 1). Na abordagem deste pacote as entradas são dadas em formato de um `array` 3D, onde a dim 1: amostras; dim 2: tempo; dim 3: variáveis, entretanto não deixando explícito a divisão das entradas e os alvos (*inputs* e *targets*, que é uma abordagem comum em pacotes sobre RNA). Além do mais, na descrição do pacote tanto as entradas como os alvos devem ter a mesma dimensão. Assim, como posso definir meu conjunto de dados para a rede neural recorrente no pacote `rnn`?

Estes seriam exemplos dos [meus dados](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4pR5oGrf-Y-QVRwOFR4YlUxakE/view?usp=sharing) de treinamento em um *data frame* (*inputs*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este os alvos (*targets*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se for o que estou pensando a sua dúvida, é sobre como arranjar os dados para treinamento. Tu tem variáveis que guardam o registro do tempo,  10 dias, então as dimensões da tua entrada fica X=(n_samples, 10, 3) , e Y=(n_samples, 10, 1). Você precisa organizar o dataset instanciando um *array* e configurando as dimensões em *dim*.

Comment: pode fazer um code exemplo?

Comment: compartilha teus dados que depois eu exemplifco pra ti, pode usar o`dput` pra isso, coloca-os na tua questão.

Comment: ok, coloquei meu dados com hyperlink.

Comment: Os valores do seus dados veio tudo zero, eu criei uns aleatórios, para exemplificação deve servir.

Comment: @RafaelToledo ok, vou testar e te dou um retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Ao que me pareceu teus dados estão organizados da seguinte forma, cada linha você tem o registro de uma única variável em 4 momentos sequencias de tempo, o **Q_t** é o valor que você quer prever baseado na sequência dos últimos 3 valores dela **Q_t_1, Q_t_2, Q_t_3**.

Portanto, você tem tal configuração:

```
n_samples <- nrow(data)
timesteps <- 3
n_variables <- 1
```

Para ajustar os dados apropriadamente para o treinamento, você tem que criar um array tridimensional. Depois, você pode iterar sobre o dataset original e alocar os valores dentro da array sample por sample.

```
data_X <- array(NA, dim=c(n_samples, timesteps, n_variables))
data_Y <- array(NA, dim=c(n_samples, 1, 1))

for(i in 1:n_samples){
        data_X[i,,1] <- unlist(data[i, c("Q_t_1", "Q_t_2", "Q_t_3")])
        data_Y[i,,1] <- unlist(data[i, "Q_t"])

}
```

Se você tivesse mais uma variável, digamos **R_t_***, ela ficaria em `data_X[i,,2] e assim por diante.

Para realizar o treinamento, segue igual ao tutorial que você mencionou, exceto que agora `seq_to_seq_unsync` deve ser `TRUE`, devido o modelo ter que retornar um único valor a partir da sequência de input. Diferente do tutorial em que o modelo retorna uma sequência de mesmo tamanho que a de input.

```
model <- trainr(Y=data_Y, X=data_X, hidden_dim=100,
                learningrate=0.1, batch_size=1, numepochs=100,
                seq_to_seq_unsync=T)

plot(colMeans(model$error), type="l")

# predita sobre o conjunto de treinamento
data_H <- predictr(model, data_X)

# compara o valor com real com a hipótese
head(cbind(data_Y, data_H))
```